# Python: Faulty transfer from database output to Folium

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to read the coordinates from a MySQL database with Python and reproduce them on a map with Folium.

But I noticed that only the last of the 43 records are output and entered into the map and I don't know why.
I have the feeling that I can't see the wood for the trees anymore.

Maybe you can help me with how to read out all 43 data sets?

I have the complete code below including a screenshot of what this code outputs:

```
import folium
import mysql
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="",
        database="firmen"
    )


if(mydb):
    print("Verbindung erfolgreich")

else:
    print("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen")


cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from leipzig")
result = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()

#13 = Longitude and 12 = Latitude
for data in result:
    ID = data[0]
    name = data[1]
    lon = data[13]
    lat = data[12]

      
mydb.close()
print("Verbindung geschlossen")



# Create a Map instance
mymap = folium.Map(location=[51.268360, 12.419357], tiles='stamentoner',
                   zoom_start=10, control_scale=True)

tooltipMeta = ID, name


folium.Marker([lon,lat], tooltip=tooltipMeta).add_to(mymap)

folium.TileLayer('stamenwatercolor').add_to(mymap)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(mymap)

# Display the map
mymap
```

[image: Screenshot of the code output]

Comment: It seems you are overwriting values in the for loop. Could you share the content in `result` variable?

Comment: I agree with @sentence. Just put the whole content inside the loop and close the connection at the very end of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sentence & @borisdonchev are right, the part where

```
folium.Marker([lon,lat], tooltip=tooltipMeta).add_to(mymap)
```

should become

```
for data in result:
    ID = data[0]
    name = data[1]
    lon = data[13]
    lat = data[12]

    tooltipMeta = ID, name

    folium.Marker([lon,lat], tooltip=tooltipMeta).add_to(mymap)
```

Comment: Have thanks

You have set me on the right path.

I will repeat the code below in full

Answer (score 0):

I first had to create the map and then access the database.

So I managed to create the markers inside the loop

```
import folium
import mysql
import mysql.connector

mymap = folium.Map(location=[51.268360, 12.419357], tiles='stamentoner',
                   zoom_start=10, control_scale=True)

folium.TileLayer('stamenwatercolor').add_to(mymap)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(mymap)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="",
        database="firmen"
    )


if(mydb):
    print("Verbindung erfolgreich")

else:
    print("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen")


cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from leipzig")
result = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()

mydb.close()
print("Verbindung geschlossen")

#13 = Longitude and 12 = Latitude
for data in result:
    ID = data[0]
    name = data[1]
    lon = data[13]
    lat = data[12]

    tooltipMeta = ID, name


    folium.Marker([lon,lat], tooltip=tooltipMeta).add_to(mymap)





# Display the map
mymap
```

[image: The correct result]